# Exporting data from Google Bigquery table to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

When exporting data from the Google bigquery table to Google cloud storage in Python, I get the error:

> Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while writing
>   data.

I checked the JSON key file and it links to the owner of the storage. What can I do?

Comment: and How can I use the GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to better inform those who will be helping you on finding the solution to your problem. A few things you can add to your question is the python code you tried running so far, the exporting operation and where it's throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

there are several reason's for this type of error
1. you give the exact path to the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS key.
2. Please check that you have writing permission in your project.
3. You have given a correct schema and their value if you writing a table, many of the times this type of error occurred due to incorrect schema value